# How can I publish an app for both iOS and macOS?

Tags: ios, macos, cross-platform, macos-big-sur

I’m working on an iPhone/iPad app exclusively with Objective-C files.

Is there a way to build a Mac app without having to duplicate many of them?

Is there a way I can make custom button files (.h, .m) that work for both iOS and macOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to add it to the platforms

[image]

[image]

and exclude the codes which wont work on MacOS with :

```
#if !targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
// Code to exclude from Mac.
#endif
```

then you need to optimize your app for MacOs , more details on :
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/mac_catalyst/optimizing_your_ipad_app_for_mac